# Android: creating an insistent alarm (ex: morning alarm, incoming call)

Tags: android, screen, alarm, vibration

I'm writing an alarm-based application, and I'm looking for a way to wake up the user insistently. Ideally, I'd like the phone to vibrate, ring, and display a message. I tried a few different options, here's what I have for the moment:

- Have the background service start an activity that vibrates & plays music.

  > problem: even with a WAKE_LOCK, it seems that the user still has to turn on the screen and unlock it to see my activity
- Use the AlarmManager with RTC_WAKEUP and a broadcast receiver to start the aforementioned activity

  > same issue
- Simply pop up a notification, which the user can click to see the activity

  > problem: stil the same issue, and also I can't get the notification to vibrate and ring, and repeat often until dismissed

What I would really like is to have a  behaviour similar to the basic Android morning alarm, or similar to receiving a phone call: regardless of whether your phone is awake or sleeping, it rings, vibrates and displays information such as a message, a photo...

Any tips on the direction to use would be greatly appreciated! I'm sure I've seen alarm apps or "fake phone call" apps do something similar, but I'm out of ideas.

Cheers

ps: in the context of this application, I think it would be reasonable to wake up the user this way. A discreet notification would not be appropriate - unless you can wake up to a single vibration :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` flag?  It looks like it should do what you want.  See here for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the one I had overlooked! Now that the screen is on, I just need to find a good way to notify the user. I guess getting a keyguard lock is not the best practice...?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by keyguard lock, but if the purpose is for an alarm which must be dismissed before the user takes any other action, it sounds like it might be a reasonable thing to do.  That said, I'm anything but a usability expert :)

Comment: It's another type of lock you can acquire to unlock the screen for a period of time (unless there's a password). For the moment I think I might leave my activity ring and vibrate behind the screen lock - it's probably safer against pocket dials. Cheers :)